# How to prevent Visual Studio from killing any process after test execution

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, silktest

I am using Visual Studio 2012 MSTest framework with Silk4NET plug in. Every time when a test case finishes running, the Application Under Test is killed. This is REALLY annoying because this makes inspection harder in that I have to re-run the test and have to manually stop the test code to investigate the issue.
Does anybody know if I can disable this feature in VS where it kills everything after test execution? Thank you!

Comment: If you run a test that is empty and just executes the base state, is the AUT still killed at the end of the test?

Comment: I have tested that, and YES even if I comment out everything in the [TestInitialize] and [TestCleanUp] blocks, it still kills it. I used the debugger, and when the program reaches the end of the [TestCleanUp] block, the AUT was not killed, but as soon as I step out of that block, I guess VS goes to an internal TearDown procedure and kills everything that it opened.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a line to the test that sets CloseOnPlaybackCleanup flag to false:

browserWindowInstance.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;

This flag was added in Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Here is an [MSDN Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/08/using-same-applicationundertest-browserwindow-across-multiple-tests.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! But how do I do the same thing for a desktop application? The comment you had was for brower tests. Thanks!

Comment: Then it's ApplicationUnderTest.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.applicationundertest.aspx